# Make items float out of a scroll view with position absolute, on React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to create a component which resides inside a scroll view. The component has a small section which pops out of the scroll view component. The below image shows how my implementation looks like on IOS.

[image: The view on ios]

However on android the edges seem to be cut off when it leaves out of the scroll view container.

[image: The view on android]

The code i have used for this implementation is as follows

```
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={_selectDate}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <View style={styles.count}>
        <Text style={styles.countText}>20</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={{ ...styles.label, ...styles.date }}>{fmtDate}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.label}>{day}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Given below is the style of the mentioned component.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    zIndex: 100,
    paddingHorizontal: SCREEN_EDGE_PADDING,
    paddingVertical: SCREEN_EDGE_PADDING,
    backgroundColor: LIGHT_GREY,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  label: {
    color: TEXT_DARKER_GREY,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: ROBOTO,
  },
  date: {
    // marginTop: 5,
    fontFamily: ROBOTO_MEDIUM,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  count: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: -2,
    top: -2,
    zIndex: 100,
    padding: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: TEXT_DARK_GREY,
  },
  countText: {
    color: WHITE,
    fontSize: 10,
  },
});
```

The scroll view in which the above component resides has no additional stylings except for some padding and margins.

Comment: Try to set `overflow: 'visible'` on your scrollView style

Comment: That didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the margin of the container, it will give space for the floating label and won't be sliced anymore.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).